# Angular: bind a local image (assets folder) to a name coming from API

Tags: angular, data-binding

Im building this small app based on the Star Wars API. I Have rendered some characters names and the selected ones gives us other info like hair color, etc. The thing is that I want to bind a local image to those selected. For example, if I click on the name Luke SkyWalker, Ill get his characteristics, but i want the local image of him to be loaded as well. How can I achieve this? The code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="people">
  <ul *ngFor="let star of people.results">
    <li (click)="onSelect(star)" [class.selected]="star === selectedPeople">{{star.name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Hair Color</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Mass</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Eye Color</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" *ngIf="selectedPeople">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople.height">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople.hair_color">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople.mass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople.eye_color">
    </div>
  </div>
<!--PICTURE-->
<div class="col" *ngIf="picture">
  <img class="img-fluid" [src]="luke"> ->This pic is harcoded

</div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  people: People;
  selectedPeople: People;
  picture=false;
  luke: string ='../../assets/luke.jpg'
  constructor(private starService: StarService) {
    this.getChars();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelect(persona: People): void {
    this.selectedPeople = persona;
    this.picture=true;
  }


  getChars() {
    this.starService.getChars().subscribe(data => {
      this.people = data;
      console.log(this.people)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try naming the image the same as the character, so luke's image is named "Luke Skywalker.jpg", and use the name to build the path

Comment: Im sorry, but I didnt get your hint; can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name the file within the assets directory to match the name of the character. For example, if the JSON came back with a name of `Luke Skywalker`, you would name the image file as `Luke Skywalker.jpg`.

In your component file, you can then create a function like so:

```
getImageUrl(person) {
    return "../../assets/" + person.name + ".jpg";
}
```

And in your HTML, you can do

```
<img [src]="getImageUrl(selectedPeople)" />
```

Comment: `<img *ngIf="selectedPeople" src="/assets/{{selectedPeople.name}}.jpg"/>`